# Error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals C:\PlasticSCM\Custom.APP.Chrysler.JNAP.QuarterGlassPickCell\Release\PFD.exe PFD

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to add to an existing project Visual Studio C++ 2008 so I imported to Visual Studio C++ 2010. I made some changes and fixed some errors. But I now have an error

"Error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals  C:\PlasticSCM\Custom.APP.Chrysler.JNAP.QuarterGlassPickCell\Release\PFD.exe PFD"

In this program, there are 5 projects but this error is on a project called PFD. I am trying to build the project (i.e. create the PFD.exe) and it says it can't find it. I need help.

Please & Thank you!

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know why I have an error. It is seems It can't find the exe it should be trying to create